# Understanding this Mutable Recursive Function using the uJson library

Tags: scala, recursion, insert, mutation, ujson

I am trying to implement an insert function using the ujson [library](https://www.lihaoyi.com/post/HowtoworkwithJSONinScala.html#traversing-json):

Here is my attempt:

```
import ujson.{Obj, Value}
import upickle.default._

object Example extends App {
  def r = transform(
    List(Map(
      "a" -> Map("b" -> Obj("c" -> List(1,2,3), "d" -> List(2,4,6))), 
      "e" -> Map("f" -> Obj("g" -> List(1,2,3)))))
  ).to(Value)

  def insert(j: ujson.Value, k: String, v: ujson.Value): Unit = j match {
    case a: ujson.Arr => a.arr.foreach(e => insert(e, k, v))
    case o: ujson.Obj =>
    if (o.obj.keySet contains k)  o.obj(k) = v
    else o.obj.values.foreach(e => insert(e, k, v))
    case _ => Nil
  }

  println(r)
  insert(r, "b", transform(None).to(Value))
  println(r)
}
```

However, this gives me output that is unchanged:

```
[{"a":{"b":{"c":[1,2,3],"d":[2,4,6]}},"e":{"f":{"g":[1,2,3]}}}]
[{"a":{"b":{"c":[1,2,3],"d":[2,4,6]}},"e":{"f":{"g":[1,2,3]}}}]
```

Given that the Value type is mutable, why does this not mutate and update the key, k, with value v for json value object r?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating `Value` anew every time you call `r` so, every changes you would make to it, are dismissed.

You create one copy when you call `println(r)`.

Then you create a separate copy with `insert(r, "b", transform(None).to(Value))`, mutate it and dismiss.

Then you are creating third copy with another `println(r)`.

If you want to refer to the same object use `val` instead of `def`.

Comment: Thanks @Mateusz, I think I made a typo - Value is mutable according this link: https://www.lihaoyi.com/post/HowtoworkwithJSONinScala.html#traversing-json

I will try to fix the insert function as it seems that is where I am messing up. I think based on what you said I will have to return a leaf node in the base case here.